# How to jsp:usebean setproperty to two different bean having same property name?

Tags: jsp

I am new to JSP Usebean.. I have tried below scenario. When I submit the form, student name is also setting into college name. Because, both bean has same property name. Is there anyway to avoid this collision and set the correct value.?

Summary.jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="student" class="demo.jsp.beans.Student" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="student"/>
    <jsp:useBean id="college" class="demo.jsp.beans.College" scope="page"></jsp:useBean>
    <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="college"/>
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
}
```

College.java

```
public class College {
  private String name;
}
```

Index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="summary.jsp">
        <table>
            <tr><td> Name</td><td>:</td><td><input name="name"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td> DOB</td><td>:</td><td><input name="dob"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td> College</td><td>:</td><td><input name="name"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td> </td><td></td><td><input type="submit"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsp:useBean` is obsolete. Just put beans in the session with:

```
BeanName beanvar = new BeanName();
beanvar.member = "whatever";
session.setAttribute("sessionvarname", beanvar);
```

And retrieve them with:

```
BeanName var = (BeanName)session.getAttribute("sessionvarname");
```

Here where you aren't even using session scope but only page scope, your code would be like:

```
demo.jsp.beans.Student student = new demo.jsp.beans.Student();
student.name = request.getParameter("student_name");

demo.jsp.beans.College college = new demo.jsp.beans.College();
college.name = request.getParameter("college_name");
```

If you then wanted to put them in the session:

```
session.setAttribute("student_bean", student);
session.setAttribute("college_bean", college);
```

To retrieve from session for use on another page:

```
demo.jsp.beans.Student student = (demo.jsp.beans.Student) session.getAttribute("student_bean");
demo.jsp.beans.College college = (demo.jsp.beans.College) session.getAttribute("college_bean");
```

You need to change your form to where the inputs have unique names:

```
        <tr><td> Name</td><td>:</td><td><input name="student_name"/></td></tr>
 ...
        <tr><td> College</td><td>:</td><td><input name="college_name"/></td></tr>
```